# Update Table B With Max(MOD_DATE) From Table A

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table A has multiple records with each having a mod_date and I can view the max(mod_date) with the following query:

```
select max(mod_date) as 'mod_date', tablename
from HemaNightly
group by tablename
```

[image]

But I'd like to update table "MaxModDate" with the these two fields: "mod_date" and "tablename" so this table will only stored a single record that contains the max(mod_date) from HemaNightly.

How should I go about this?

Thanks,

Comment: Is `Mod_Date` guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: No, and mostly like won't be unique.

Comment: Do you want the resulting table to have: only a single row regardless of any other values in `tablename`, i.e. delete all rows where `tablename <> 'HemaNightly'`; or a single row where `tablename = 'HemaNightly'` and possibly some other rows with other values in `tablename`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it will work for duplicated max date:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT, d DATE, n VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, '20150101', 'HemaNightly'),
(2, '20150105', 'HemaNightly'),
(3, '20150109', 'HemaNightly'),
(4, '20150110', 'HemaDailyly'),
(5, '20150111', 'HemaDailyly'),
(6, '20150111', 'HemaDailyly')

;WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY n ORDER BY d DESC, n) AS rn FROM @t)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn <> 1

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Output:

```
id  d           n
3   2015-01-09  HemaNightly
5   2015-01-11  HemaDailyly
```